# No module named 'django' in standalone Django App

Tags: python, django, faker

I installed Django on Windows 10, Django Version 3, Python 3.8 from Conda, with env, on VS Code

My Django works fine without any problem and my App and Project also works fine, but I decided to use [Faker](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/fakerclass.html) to generate some fake data in my DB, I have to mention that my Model works and connected successfully to my DB and migration process was successful without any problem.
I write this Standalone app for Faker to run it whenever I need manually:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'first_project.settings')

import django
django.setup()

# Implement Fake Population script here.
import random
from first_app.models import AccessRecord, Topic, Webpage
from faker import Faker 

fakegen = Faker()
topics = ['Search', 'Social', 'Marketplace', 'News', 'Games']

def add_topic():
    t = Topic.objects.get_or_create(top_name=random.choice(topics))[0]
    t.save()
    return t

def populate(N=5):
    for entry in range (N):

        # Get the topic for the entry
        top = add_topic() 

        # Create the fake data for that entry
        fake_url = fakegen.url()
        fake_date = fakegen.date()
        fake_name = fakegen.company()

        # Create the new webpage entry
        webpg = Webpage.objects.get_or_create(topic=top,url=fake_url, name=fake_name)[0]


        # Create a fake access record for that webpage
        acc_rec = AccessRecord.objects.get_or_create(name=webpg,date=fake_date)[0]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('Population Script!')
    populate(20)
    print('Population Completed!')
```

But whenever I run this code, I get this error:

```
> (myDjangoEnv) C:\my_path\first-project
> C:/Users/HPTav/anaconda3/python.exe 
> c:/my_path/first_project/populate_first_app.py
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/my_path/first_project/populate_first_app.py", line 4, in 
  <module>
  import django
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
> (myDjangoEnv) C:\my_path\first-project>
```

- I replaced the path with my_path to make it easier for you when you read the console error.

This is my Django project structure:

[image]

I am sure I have Django, as I said my Django app and project works fine.

- I checked it by this way to make sure I have Django on this folder:
  [image]

This project is available in GitHub:

https://github.com/hptavakoli/django_first_app

Comment: can you see or check by placing the import django on above below import os?

Comment: I checked it, but I got the same error,

Comment: The better way now please upload ur full project on github and then send us the link of that project that we can get the whole project codes and utilize ur errors. thanks.

Comment: Great idea, thanks, it's a simple test project: https://github.com/hptavakoli/django_first_app

Comment: i run ur project successfully no errors occurs. see https://imgur.com/9o3RNzR.png

Comment: i think u have a problem with ur Env, or the directory nothing else.

Comment: Exactly. as I said the project works fine, but I define a standalone file "population_first_app.py", it is in the main project, root folder, I also selected it in the image of my project structure in the original question above, when I want to run that file, it doesn't work.
I have to say that I do not call this file in my project and I just want to run it one time to generate some fake data into my DB.

Comment: I think there is something else, not env or so, because I can run project on my system as well, the only thing which doesn't work is this population file

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you don't have django installed, install it using this command:

```
pip install django
```

In your Command prompt.
Visit this site for additional info: [Installing django using pip](https://pypi.org/project/Django/)

Comment: I have it as I said I can run my Django app and I can open the Django admin, use it and everything works fine, just this file doesn't work, and I think it is not logical to install Django again inside my env when I am pretty sure that I have it

Comment: That sounds odd because your program fails to pass line 4 which is the import itself. Have you tried to re-install django/Are you sire you have it installed?

Comment: Actually I didn't try to reinstall it, I use env and do you know what could happen if I try to reinstall Django now when my env is activated and also I already installed it one-time before? I mean inside the env, it will be refresh everything or just recheck it?
Also, considering my Django app works fine, is there any possibility to have a problem with the Django itself? I mean I think it has to be installed, otherwise how I can run my local server, create my model and open the Django admin and so on?

Comment: I update my post and added a screenshot at the end of that about my Django status, please check it, I think it could show that I have Django on this env.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is this:

> "Add 'python' while calling populate_first_app.py in the terminal."

```
python populate_first_app.py
```